# How to import data from MySQL to Processing using PHP file?

Tags: php, mysql, processing

I need to import some data from MySQL database to analyze and display using [Processing](https://processing.org/) 
I have PHP code to query and get data from MySQL. Is there any way I could call my PHP from processing? Appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance,
Hasala

Comment: Can u call an http url? If so u are in

Comment: @DrewPierce yes, I can call even a http *.php file. But I am unable to call this https:// *.php file.

Comment: It's a socket and stream. Not an elegant protocol ssl/tls engine that's for sure

Answer (score 1):

This below is a total poach from internet. I wouldn't know Processing if it fell on my head.

So yes it seems quite possible.

```
String ip="12.215.42.19";
String[] data=loadStrings("http://api.hostip.info/get_html.php?position=true&ip="+ip);
//will give an array of strings, one per line e.g.
/*
data[0]="Country: UNITED STATES (US)"
data[1]="City: Sugar Grove, IL"
data[2]=""
data[3]="Latitude: 41.7696"
data[4]="Longitude: -88.4588"
data[5]="IP: 12.215.42.19"
*/
```

Edit:
Pretend the below .html is a .php

```
String lines[] = loadStrings("http://processing.org/about/index.html");
println("there are " + lines.length + " lines");
for (int i = 0 ; i < lines.length; i++) {
  println(lines[i]);
```

From:

https://processing.org/reference/loadStrings_.html

Comment: I tried like you said. But I get an error saying javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException:

My php is a link with https, would that be a problem? When I go to link from my browser it displays the result as array of Strings. What could be the issue?

Comment: Clearly SSL gets in the way and processing cannot handshake it

Comment: Sadly they named the language what they did. Messes up google search. It's like searching on `the`

Comment: So, is there anyway to fix this? I have no access to change any modifications from the server side. Any change I can do to client to fix this? Appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: You need to get something you can call that can talk ssl. Perhaps a third party library. A shell. I don't see Processing doing it natively.

Comment: ok I will try to find one. Like you said it is a total mess when searching something related to this.

Comment: A hint on searching, not really a solution, but... Is to search using  `_query_ site:processing.org` . You can try also using processing.org instead of processing in your regular sentence...

Comment: @DrewPierce I was able to connect to the server using http:// protocol by connecting to a different network. thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: Just mark answers as helpful or answered with feedback so others that follow don't just stop and give up